# Deleting NULL geometries and duplicate nodes from table using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, null, duplication

I run the command to delete null geometry from a table:

```sql
delete from table where geom is null
```

And delete duplicate nodes by running the command:

```sql
update table set geom = ST_Multi(ST_Simplify(geom,0));
```

How to run the above commands in all tables using a loop?

Answer (score 6):

This requires a procedural execution of *dynamic SQL* - best applied with a `DO` block.

Since we are only looking at modifying columns of type `GEOMETRY`, we can identify the respective relations easily through the `geometry_columns` *View*:

```
DO
$DO$
  DECLARE
    r record;
    
  BEGIN 
    FOR r in (
      SELECT
        srid,
        f_table_name,
        f_table_schema,
        f_geometry_column
      FROM
        geometry_columns
      -- WHERE
      --  <FILTER>
    ) LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Deleting from table %.% [Geometry column: % | SRID: %]...', r.f_table_schema, r.f_table_name, r.f_geometry_column, r.srid;
       
      EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $FORMAT$
          DELETE
          FROM
            %1$I.%2$I
          WHERE
            %3$I IS NULL
          );
        $FORMAT$,
        r.f_table_schema, r.f_table_name, r.f_geometry_column
      );
      --COMMIT;
      
      RAISE NOTICE 'Updating table %.% [Geometry column: % | SRID: %]...', r.f_table_schema, r.f_table_name, r.f_geometry_column, r.srid;
       
      EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $FORMAT$
          UPDATE
            %1$I.%2$I
          SET %3$I = ST_SetSRID(
                       ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints(%3$I, 0),
                       %4%s
                     )
          ;
        $FORMAT$,
        r.f_table_schema, r.f_table_name, r.f_geometry_column, r.srid
      );
      
      --COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
  END;
$DO$
;
```

**Note:**

I use [`ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints.html) instead of the more costly `ST_Simplify` - seems to be what you are after.

---

In PostgreSQL 11.0 and above, `DO` blocks allow for explicit [*Transaction Management*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html); adding intermediate `COMMIT`s (commented out in the code snippet above) between operations (i.e. `DELETE` & `UPDATE`) should greatly increase performance for many and/or large tables, as the intermediate snapshots of those modifications do not need to be kept isolated.

Keep in mind, though, that a `COMMIT` persists changes *immediately*, so any error encountered at a later point in the execution loop *cannot* `ROLLBACK` earlier changes!

---

Make sure you test and verify the record set passed to the `FOR` loop prior to executing the `DO` block; apply any schema or table filter logic needed:

```
SELECT
  srid,
  f_table_name,
  f_table_schema,
  f_geometry_column
FROM
  geometry_columns
-- WHERE
--   <FILTER>
;
```